# Does Comparator work differently with wrapper class?

Tags: java, comparator

I keep failing sorting student IDs from the database , after long time figuring it out as to why it gets sorted incorrectly, I concluded that this *Comparator* works differently with the Wrapper Class ?

```
public class comparatorDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<Integer> IDComparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer firstID, Integer secondID) {
            return firstID < secondID ? (-1) : (firstID == secondID ? (0) : (1));
        }
            };

  System.out.println(IDComparator.compare(new Integer(1), new Integer(1))); // prints 1
  System.out.println(IDComparator.compare((1),(1))); // prints 0
 }  }
```

What is going on here ?

Comment: Please use `Integer.valueOf()` so frequently used `Integer` objects gets cached!

Comment: @Unihedron - no need.  The auto-boxing in the second call to `compare` above takes care of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, when using `==` to compare two references, the result will be `true` if and only if the two references point to the same exact object. So when you are comparing `new Integer(1)` with `new Integer(1)`, `==` will return `false`

When using `==` to compare to primitives (like `int`) then `true` will be returned when the values are equal.

One solution is to use `firstID.equals(secondID)`

Check out [this](http://java67.blogspot.gr/2012/11/difference-between-operator-and-equals-method-in.html) for more information

**UPDATE**

As mentioned by JBNizet, you can replace

`return firstID < secondID ? (-1) : (firstID == secondID ? (0) : (1));`

with

`return firstID.compareTo(secondID);`

which makes the code a lot easier to read and of course uses the correct comparison.

Comment: An easier solution is to simply use `return firstID.compareTo(secondID)`, which returns the desired result.

Comment: @JBNizet As usual, you are correct :). My mind didn't even go there since I wanted to show the diffence between `==` and `equals`. Do you mind if I add your suggestion to the answer? I will of course mention that you pointed it out!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because there is a static cache of `Integer` objects - one for every value from `-128` to `127`.  This is used for auto-boxing, and a few other operations.

In `IDComparator.compare(new Integer(1), new Integer(1))`, two new `Integer` objects are created, then compared with `==`.  Because they're not the same object, `==` returns `false` and the comparator returns `1`.

In `IDComparator.compare((1),(1))`, the `Integer` value of `1` is returned twice from the static cache; but it's just one `Integer` object.  So `==` returns `true` and the comparator returns `0`.